# How to delete rows from a cursor with criteria from another cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 2 cursors that have a unique number that connects each other, say Student_ID.

If there is same Student_ID found in the first cursor, I have to delete it from the second cursor.

I found something like this but don't really understand how it goes:

```
open c1;  
fetch c1 into cnumber;

if c1%notfound then
   cnumber := 9999;

else
   DELETE FROM courses_tbl
     WHERE CURRENT OF c1;

   COMMIT;
```

This is my first time doing Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Do you mean delete from another _cursor_ or do you mean delete from a table? What problem are you actually attempting to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First example reflects yours approach. It is not bad but it is good to minimalise the number of delete statements.

```
CREATE TABLE so_courses_tbl
(
    col VARCHAR2(10)
)
;
-- table so_courses_tbl created.

INSERT INTO so_courses_tbl VALUES(1);
-- 1 rows inserted.

DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT  1
        FROM    DUAL;

    cnumber  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN  c1;
    FETCH c1 INTO cnumber;
    CLOSE c1;

    DELETE
    FROM    so_courses_tbl
    WHERE   col = cnumber;

    COMMIT;
END;
-- anonymous block completed

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM so_courses_tbl;
-- 0
```

2) This is how you can do it in a one step. You can use variables is the WHERE clause to make it more flexible (if you need it...)

```
INSERT INTO so_courses_tbl VALUES('X');
INSERT INTO so_courses_tbl VALUES('X');
INSERT INTO so_courses_tbl VALUES('X');
-- 1 rows inserted.
-- 1 rows inserted.
-- 1 rows inserted.

BEGIN
    DELETE
    FROM    so_courses_tbl  c
    WHERE   EXISTS
            (
                SELECT  1
                FROM    DUAL  d
                WHERE   c.col = d.dummy
            );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of deleted rows: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);

    COMMIT;
END;
-- Number of deleted rows: 3
```

Give it a shot and let us know how it went.